# Learning GUIs - handling button actions with actionPerformed()

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning GUIs from tutorials, and could do with a few pointers on the best way to approach something that currently isn't working.

Background: I have a class containing my main method, which extends JFrame, and initialises a class that extends JPanel (panel1).

panel1 contains a hard-coded .txt file URL, and the contents of that file determines what is displayed in the frame (this works fine). I'm trying to modify the programme so as the user can choose the .txt file from their machine...

To do this, I've created a third class called panel2 (extends JPanel, implements ActionListener) which contains a JButton. (I've created a new JPanel, because there will be further buttons, so it provides the layout).

I've picked out the code from panel2 relevant to what is going wrong:

```
private String f;
private JButton b;
```

In the constructor:

```
b = new JButton("Button");
add(b);
```

Methods:

```
public String getName() {
    return f;
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if (e.getSource() == b) {
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    this.f = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

If I call getName(), it returns null. I need to pass the string into panel1 to replace the hard-coded URL, and I intend to do that using getName(). I know I am doing something very basic wrong here!! Any pointers would be v much appreciated.

Comment: One thing missing from your code snippet is actually listening to the button event - b.addActionListener(this) in the constructor. You do have this right?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry - I forgot to include that. Your idea of using listeners seems so much more logical and will definitely look at it, but I still don't understand why nothing is being stored in f here and it's bugging me! :)

Comment: Part of your problem is knowing when the user makes a change/selection, for this I would suggest you do some research in the observer pattern, of which ActionListener is an example. When the user makes a selection, your "button" panel would generate a new event, notifying however was interests that a change has taken place, then they could either call getName on the component or possibly get the value from the event.

Comment: Also note, getName is already defined in the parent class, while this method is relatively benign, you'll want to be careful with your method naming in the future, as it could effect the way your program executes

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly...

But if you want the panel1 to react on choosing the file in panel2, you need to have a reference from your panel2 to your panel1.
There are different ways to do this:

- You could simply give the panel1 object as an argument in the constructor of panel2, and call a method of panel1 when you need to.
- Or you could use a listener. For instance, panel2 could fire a property change event for the url property. As your panel2 extends JPanel, it already has all the methods for handling property change listeners (see the methods  `firePropertyChange` and `addPropertyChangeListener`). Then have the panel1 listen to this event.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out. At the moment, panel1 and panel2 are initialised in my main method. I then call String a = panel2.getFileName(); method on panel2, and pass the returned string (the file URL) into panel1 as a parameter in the constructor. Panel1 p = new Panel1(a);
The problem is that .getFileName(); doesn't return the file path. It isn't getting stored in f at this point:  this.f = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

Comment: You can read the "How to Write a Property Change Listener" tutorial from java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html). The idea in this case would be to fire the event that your property f has changed (by calling firePropertyChange just after your assignment of f), and have panel1 listen to that event to start loading the file.